# Simple dependency management for a Python project

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

I am coming from Java background and completely new at Python.

Now I have got a small project with a few Python files that contain a few imports. I know I does not have the imported dependencies installed on my computer, so I try to figure out the required dependencies and run `pip` to install them.

I would like to do it differently. I would prefer to have the dependencies listed in a single file and install them automatically during the build process.

Does it make sense ? If it does I have a few questions:

- How to list the project dependencies required to install by `pip` ?
- How to run `pip` to install the dependencies from the list ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A common way to manage dependencies for a python project is via a file in root of the project named "requirements.txt". An easy way to make this is:

1. Setup a python virtualenv for your project
2. Manually install the required modules via pip
3. Execute `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate the requirements file

You can then install all the dependencies in other locations using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

If you want dependencies to be installed automatically when other people `pip install` your package, you can use `install_requires()` in your `setup.py`.

Comment: Thank you. Just one minor question: what is `python virtualenv` you suggested set up ?

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: The link to the guide no longer works, try this one (for English): https://python-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenv

Comment: Their is a good official tutorial about package management and virtual environment : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: While the above method still works and is valid, in 2023 there are better tools for managing these things. I personally recommend [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)