# Python - Best practice for user-friendly way of checking for missing library dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, dependency-management

Let's say my Python 3.6 script requires `bar` in the library `foo`, which it `import`s at the beginning:

```
from foo import bar
```

What I'd like to do is for the script to attempt the `import`, and give feedback to a downstream user if `foo` is not available on their system and that they should install it.

So far, I've managed to hack together this solution which is probably not very good:

```
try:
    from foo import bar
except:
    print("Need `foo` library installed")
    exit(1)
```

I used `print()` because I hope this can be a direct message to the user, but not sure if that's a good idea in the context of exception handling?

Also, there are at least two more problems here:

1. The `except` clause would apply to *any* error that happens during `import` including cases where the error is something other than the absence of `foo`. So this probably isn't a good use of exception handling?
2. My script `import`s multiple libraries, and I have to create a chunk like the above for each one!

I briefly considered creating a `for` loop that goes through a `list` of library dependencies and `import` each one. E.g.:

```
list_of_libraries: list = ["foo", "lorem", "ipsum"]
for library in list_of_libraries:
    try:
        import library
    except:
        print("Need " + library + " library installed")
        exit(1)
```

However, this also looks bad to me because:

- Each loop iteration `import`s the whole library
- It would fail because I don't think `import` takes a `string`?
- It doesn't really solve problem 1 above.

Am I stupidly missing something here? What's a good way to implement this? Thank you.

**EDIT:** There are existing answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828879/simple-dependency-management-for-a-python-project) which discusses how to list dependencies in `requirements.txt` and installing them with `pip`. However, my question is focused on solutions I can implement inside my Python script *to catch missing libraries and prompting the user to install them*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple dependency management for a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828879/simple-dependency-management-for-a-python-project)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to do nothing. If an import fails there will already be a message (the exception traceback) that tells the user what is missing.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 but that isn't exactly what I am after. The linked answer is about dealing with `pip` and best practices such as using `requirements.txt`, but I am talking about things I can do within my Python script.

Answer (score 1):

### Exception Clause

You can catch `ModuleNotFoundError` (exists as of Python 3.6) or `ImportError` (for all Python versions) to restrict your `except` clause to cases of import troubles. `ModuleNotFoundError` is a subclass of `ImportError`, so catching `ImportError` will work in all versions of Python.

### Error Output

Errors in standard linux applications would be written to stderr instead of stdout. So instead of using plain `print`, you would do as follows:

```
import sys

try:
    from foo import bar
except ImportError:
    print("Need `foo` library installed", file=sys.stderr)
    exit(1)
```

You can test it by redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`. You will still see the error message:

```
$ python foobar.py >> /dev/null
Need `foo` library installed
```

### Better Handling Possible?

As for a better method than writing each import individually or looping over the required libraries, I unfortunately do not know. I have seen the `try except ImportError` pattern been [used for compatibility](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1393) between modules that were renamed from Python 2 to Python 3. So for individual libraries it seems to be normal, but I have not seen anybody mass check imports.

Comment: Thank you @Aufziehvogel! That's quite helpful already. As for "better handling", I don't think `import` works with `list` items of `string` type when looping over required libraries, is there a way to create a loop that does this another way?

Comment: I think you want to use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), especially `import_module`. But then you have your module assigned to a variable and cannot use it like a normal module. People seem to solve this by assigning to `global()`. It works, but I do not know if there are negative side-effects. During my trials this worked: `globals()['foo'] = importlib.import_module('foo')`, then you can call functions like `foo.my_function()`.